# Use dbms_xmldom.writetofile without a Named Directory

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write an XML file using PL/SQL using the procedure `dbms_xmldom.writetofile`. However, the code above only works when I supply a named directory taken from `DBA_DIRECTORIES` like below:

```
procedure PRINT_XML (p_xml          xmltype
                    ,p_requestid    number)
is

    l_filename      varchar2(100);
    doc             dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
    l_directory     request_history.OUTPUTWORKDIRECTORY%type;
    l_dml_stmnt     request_history.OUTPUTWORKDIRECTORY%type;

begin

    l_filename          := 'JPK_Accounting_Books_'||g_jpk_ess_request_id||'.xml';
    
    doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(p_xml);
    dbms_xmldom.writetofile(doc, 'TMP/'||l_filename);
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        write_to_aflog(p_module     => 'JG.JPK.JE_PL_JPK_ACCT_BOOKS.PRINT_XML'
                  ,    p_message    => 'Error in PRINT_XML '||sqlerrm);
        raise;
end PRINT_XML;
```

I was hoping to supply the directory programmatically, as the directory changes per execution, like below:

```
procedure PRINT_XML (p_xml          xmltype
                    ,p_requestid    number)
is

    l_filename      varchar2(100);
    doc             dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
    l_directory     request_history.OUTPUTWORKDIRECTORY%type;
    l_dml_stmnt     request_history.OUTPUTWORKDIRECTORY%type;

begin

    l_filename          := 'JPK_Accounting_Books_'||g_jpk_ess_request_id||'.xml';
    
    select  OUTPUTWORKDIRECTORY
    into    l_directory
    from    request_history -- ESS
    where   requestid = p_requestid;
        
    doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(p_xml);
    dbms_xmldom.writetofile(doc, l_directory||'/'||l_filename);
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        write_to_aflog(p_module     => 'JG.JPK.JE_PL_JPK_ACCT_BOOKS.PRINT_XML'
                  ,    p_message    => 'Error in PRINT_XML '||sqlerrm);
        raise;
end PRINT_XML;
```

However, i am getting an error `ORA-29280: invalid directory path`. I have tried to do an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY...` but i am getting: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`.

I cannot do the following due to the organization's policies:

1. Add another permanent directory in `DBA_DIRECTORIES`
2. Provide additional privileges to the current user

Is there another way to use dbms_xmldom.writetofile (or something similar) without creating a named directory?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that probably the path does not exist or you have no write privileges over the directory.

```
SQL> select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'YOUR DIRECTORY' ;
```

If you got no rows, you need to address this with your DBA, as either the directory does not exist or you have no privileges over it. A database directory is a combination of two elements:

- The database directory is a pointer or reference to a location in the operating system.
- The path of that directory must exist and the user who runs the process must possess read and write privileges on it.

For the second issue, the problem is that the user who owns the procedure has not been granted with the system privilege CREATE ANY DIRECTORY. Your DBA must grant the CREATE ANY DIRECTORY privilege over your user, although I don't recommend it. Granting ANY privileges is a bad security practice.

Creating directories is normally a task for your DBA. I don't foresee a scenario when you need to create them dynamically, as long as you have also to create the underlying directory in the Filesystem ( Linux ) or Windows drive, depending of your operating system.

**Given your special circumstances, you have no option with this. You need to reevaluate the solution. Perhaps you might use WRITETOCLOB instead of WRITETOFILE , then spool the result in your client side by sqlplus instead**

Comment: yes, the first issue was actually outlined in the post: I cannot create new directories and update directories. The Path exists and is valid, but is not a named directory.

Comment: if the path exists, the only way the database can write on it is by using a directory object. Besides, if the path exists, I guess it is for your program to dump the xml content. If so, why your dba cannot create the database object ( directory ) to point to the location that you said already exists ?

Comment: it's a proprietary product and we can't create new directories. It's a restriction set by the development management, not my own decision. Also, the directory changes per execution. for example, the 1st execution's (process 101) file would be at `/101/out` and the 2nd would be at `/102/out`. it's how it was designed, and i cannot change it sadly