# Printing Large XML using PL/SQL results into ORA-10260: limit size (1048576) of the PGA heap set by event 10261 exceeded

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

We are currently writing a large piece of code in XML from a large query like below:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    
    lc_xml          xmltype;
    --g_request_id  number := 233;
    g_request_id    number := 206;
    g_subsection    varchar2(10) := 'ALL';
    g_affname       varchar2(10) := 'AFF';
    g_number_format VARCHAR2(30) := 'FM999999999999999999999990D00';
    
    c_blob          clob;
    v_offset        number := 1;
    v_chunk_size    number := 32767;
    l_length        NUMBER := 0;

begin

    WITH
    gljournal as
    (
        SELECT  context_request_id
            ,case
                when INFO_CHAR45 is null then null
                else INFO_CHAR45||' '||INFO_NUMBER14
            end jrnl_RepSeqName_Number
            ,   REGEXP_REPLACE(INFO_CHAR32,'[^[a-z,A-Z,0-9,chr(0)-chr(127)[:space:]]]*','') INFO_CHAR32
            ,case
                when INFO_CHAR46 is null then null
                else INFO_CHAR46 ||' '|| INFO_NUMBER15
            end Subledger_Doc_Number
            ,   INFO_CHAR33
            ,   INFO_DATE4
            ,   INFO_DATE2
            ,   INFO_DATE3
            ,   INFO_CHAR39
            ,   sum((nvl(info_number4, 0) - nvl(info_number11, 0))) tot_jrnl_amt
        from    xx_xml_table
        where   section_code = 'GL_JOURNALS'
        and     sub_section_code in ('MANUAL', 'SUBLEDGER')
        and     context_request_id = g_request_id
        group by
                context_request_id
            ,   INFO_CHAR45
            ,   INFO_NUMBER14
            ,   INFO_CHAR32
            ,   INFO_CHAR46
            ,   INFO_NUMBER15
            ,   INFO_CHAR33
            ,   INFO_DATE4
            ,   INFO_DATE2
            ,   INFO_DATE3
            ,   INFO_CHAR39
    )
    SELECT  XMLElement("tns:JPK"
            ,   XMLATTRIBUTES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xmlns:xsi"
                        ,    'http://jpk.mf.gov.pl/wzor/2016/03/09/03091/' AS "xmlns:tns"
                        ,    'http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2016/01/25/eD/DefinicjeTypy/' as "xmlns:etd"
                        ,    'http://jpk.mf.gov.pl/wzor/2016/03/09/03091/Schemat_JPK_KR(1)_v1-0.xsd' as "xsi:schemaLocation")
            ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:Naglowek"
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodFormularza", XMLATTRIBUTES(SUB_SECTION_CODE AS "kodSystemowy", INFO_CHAR1 AS "wersjaSchemy"), 'JPK_KR')
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:WariantFormularza", INFO_CHAR2)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:CelZlozenia", INFO_CHAR2)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataWytworzeniaJPK", INFO_CHAR3)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataOd", INFO_DATE1)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataDo", INFO_DATE2)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DomyslnyKodWaluty", INFO_CHAR6)
                        ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodUrzedu", INFO_CHAR7))
            ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:Podmiot1"
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu"
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:NIP", INFO_CHAR8)
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:PelnaNazwa", INFO_CHAR4)
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:REGON", INFO_CHAR5))
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:AdresPodmiotu"
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:KodKraju", INFO_CHAR9)      -- country
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Wojewodztwo", INFO_CHAR10)  -- state
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Powiat", INFO_CHAR11)       -- county
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Gmina", INFO_CHAR12)        -- province
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Ulica", INFO_CHAR13)        -- address1
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:NrDomu", INFO_CHAR14)       -- building
                    --, case when INFO_CHAR15 is not null then
                    --  XMLELEMENT("etd:NrLokalu", INFO_CHAR15) end -- floor_number
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Miejscowosc", INFO_CHAR16)  -- City
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:KodPocztowy", INFO_CHAR17)  -- Postal Code
                    ,   XMLELEMENT("etd:Poczta", INFO_CHAR18)))     -- address2
        ,   CASE WHEN g_subsection IN ('ALL', 'TRIAL_BALANCE') THEN
            (select XMLAGG(XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT("tns:ZOiS", XMLATTRIBUTES('G' AS "typ")
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodKonta", DECODE(g_affname,'AFF', info_char31, info_char49))                       -- Account, AccountingFlexField
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisKonta", info_char32)                                                        -- AccountDescription
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:TypKonta", info_char35)                                                         -- AccountType
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodZespolu", SUBSTR(info_char34, -1))                                           -- ACCT_LEVEL2_VALUE
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisZespolu", info_char35)                                                      -- AccountType
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodKategorii", SUBSTR(info_char33, -3))                                         -- ACCT_LEVEL3_VALUE
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisKategorii", info_char32)                                                    -- AccountDescription
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodPodkategorii", info_char31)                                                  -- Account
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisPodkategorii", info_char32)                                                 -- AccountDescription
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:BilansOtwarciaWinien", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number3,0)),g_number_format))       -- OpeningDebitBalance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:BilansOtwarciaMa", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number4,0)),g_number_format))           -- OpeningCreditBalance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:ObrotyWinien", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number5,0)),g_number_format))               -- Period_Debit_Balance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:ObrotyMa", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number6,0)),g_number_format))                   -- Period_Credit_Balance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:ObrotyWinienNarast", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number8,0)),g_number_format))         -- ClosingDebitBalance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:ObrotyMaNarast", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number9,0)),g_number_format))             -- ClosingCreditBalance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:SaldoWinien", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number8,0)),g_number_format))                -- ClosingDebitBalance
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:SaldoMa", to_char(sum(NVL(info_number9,0)),g_number_format))                    -- ClosingCreditBalance
                )))
            from    xx_xml_table
            where   section_code = 'GL_ACCOUNTS'
            and     sub_section_code = 'BALANCES'
            and     context_request_id = g_request_id
            and     info_number7 <> 0        -- Exclude Accounts with No Balances
            group by
                    info_char31
                ,   info_char35
                ,   info_char34
                ,   info_char33
                ,   info_char32
                ,   info_char49)
            END
        -- Manual and Subledger Journals
        ,   CASE WHEN g_subsection IN ('ALL', 'GL_JOURNALS') THEN
            (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT("tns:Dziennik", XMLATTRIBUTES('G' AS "typ")
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:LpZapisuDziennika", rownum)                                     -- rownum
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:NrZapisuDziennika", jrnl_RepSeqName_Number)                     -- Journal : Reporting Sequence Name + Number
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisDziennika", INFO_CHAR32)                                    -- Description of the Journal
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:NrDowoduKsiegowego", Subledger_Doc_Number)                      -- Subledger Document Number
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:RodzajDowodu", INFO_CHAR33)                                     -- Source document type to which line relates
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataOperacji", INFO_DATE4)                                      -- Actual Sales Date or Purchase Date
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataDowodu", INFO_DATE2)                                        -- Journal creation date.
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DataKsiegowania", INFO_DATE3)                                   -- Journal Date
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodOperatora", INFO_CHAR39)                                     -- User name / ID of the person who created
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:OpisOperacji", INFO_CHAR32)                                     -- Description of the transaction
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:DziennikKwotaOperacji",to_char(tot_jrnl_amt,g_number_format))   -- Journal Total Amount
                )))
            from    gljournal)
            END
        -- Manual Journal Summary
        ,   CASE WHEN g_subsection IN ('ALL', 'GL_JOURNALS') THEN
            (SELECT XMLELEMENT("tns:DziennikCtrl"
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:LiczbaWierszyDziennika", COUNT(context_request_id)) -- Count
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:SumaKwotOperacji", to_char(SUM(tot_jrnl_amt), g_number_format)) -- Sum
                )
            from    gljournal
            group by context_request_id)
            END
        -- Subledger Journal
        ,   CASE WHEN g_subsection IN ('ALL', 'ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS') THEN
            (SELECT XMLAGG(XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT("tns:KontoZapis", XMLATTRIBUTES('G' AS "typ")
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:LpZapisu", rownum)
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:NrZapisu", INFO_CHAR45 || ' ' || INFO_NUMBER7)              --Journal : Reporting Sequence Name + Number
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodKontaWinien", 
                    DECODE(g_affname,'AFF', INFO_CHAR31, INFO_CHAR49))                          --Debit Account ID
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KwotaWinien", to_char(INFO_NUMBER3, g_number_format))       --Amount of transaction on the debit side
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KwotaWinienWaluta", to_char(INFO_NUMBER1, g_number_format)) --Currency Amount of transaction on the debit side entry
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodWalutyWinien", INFO_CHAR35)                              --Currency Code for the debit side entry
                ,   XMLFOREST(INFO_CHAR34 as "tns:OpisZapisuWinien")                            --Description of the transaction on the debit side
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodKontaMa",                                
                    DECODE(g_affname,'AFF', INFO_CHAR31, INFO_CHAR49))                          --Credit Account ID
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KwotaMa", to_char(info_number4, g_number_format))           --Amount of transaction on the credit side
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KwotaMaWaluta", to_char(INFO_NUMBER2, g_number_format))     --Currency Amount of transaction on the credit side entry
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:KodWalutyMa", INFO_CHAR35)                      --Currency Code for the credit side entry
                ,   XMLFOREST(INFO_CHAR34 as "tns:OpisZapisuMa"))                   --Description of the transaction on the credit side
                ))
            from    xx_xml_table acct
            where   1=1
            and     section_code = 'GL_JOURNALS'
            and     sub_section_code in ('MANUAL', 'SUBLEDGER')
            and     context_request_id = g_request_id
            )
            END
        -- Subledger Journal Summary
        ,   CASE WHEN g_subsection IN ('ALL', 'ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS') THEN
            (select XMLELEMENT("tns:KontoZapisCtrl"
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:LiczbaWierszyKontoZapisj", count(context_request_id))
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:SumaWinien", to_char(sum(nvl(info_number3, 0)), g_number_format))
                ,   XMLELEMENT("tns:SumaMa", to_char(sum(nvl(info_number4, 0)), g_number_format)))
            from    xx_xml_table
            where   1=1
            and     section_code = 'GL_JOURNALS'
            and     sub_section_code in ('MANUAL', 'SUBLEDGER')
            and     context_request_id = g_request_id
            group by context_request_id)
            END
        )
    into    lc_xml
    FROM    xx_xml_table
    WHERE   SECTION_CODE = 'SH'
    and     context_request_id = g_request_id;
    
    -- i previously used this but it wasn't pretty printed
    -- c_blob := lc_xml.getclobval();

    -- i used XMLSERIALIZE here so that it will be pretty printed
    SELECT  XMLSERIALIZE( DOCUMENT lc_xml AS CLOB INDENT SIZE=2 )
    into    c_blob
    from    dual;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
    
    l_length := dbms_lob.getlength( c_blob );
    
    loop
    exit when v_offset > l_length;
        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dbms_lob.substr( c_blob, v_chunk_size, v_offset ));
        v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
    end loop;
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data Found!');
END;
```

This works when the dataset retrieved from the select statement is small (when using request_id := 206), the output is like below:

```
<tns:JPK xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://jpk.mf.gov.pl/wzor/2016/03/09/03091/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/dziedzinowe/mf/2016/01/25/eD/DefinicjeTypy/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jpk.mf.gov.pl/wzor/2016/03/09/03091/Schemat_JPK_KR(1)_v1-0.xsd">
  <tns:Naglowek>
    <tns:KodFormularza kodSystemowy="JPK_KR (1)" wersjaSchemy="1-0">JPK_KR</tns:KodFormularza>
    <tns:WariantFormularza>1</tns:WariantFormularza>
    <tns:CelZlozenia>1</tns:CelZlozenia>
    <tns:DataWytworzeniaJPK>2020-06-24T08:16:21Z</tns:DataWytworzeniaJPK>
    <tns:DataOd>2005-01-01</tns:DataOd>
    <tns:DataDo>2005-01-31</tns:DataDo>
    <tns:DomyslnyKodWaluty>PLN</tns:DomyslnyKodWaluty>
    <tns:KodUrzedu>0202</tns:KodUrzedu>
  </tns:Naglowek>
  <tns:Podmiot1>
    <tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu>
      <etd:NIP>5270201492</etd:NIP>
      <etd:PelnaNazwa>Vision Poland Report</etd:PelnaNazwa>
      <etd:REGON>SYSREGON12134</etd:REGON>
    </tns:IdentyfikatorPodmiotu>
    <tns:AdresPodmiotu>
      <etd:KodKraju>PL</etd:KodKraju>
      <etd:Wojewodztwo>mazowieckie</etd:Wojewodztwo>
      <etd:Powiat>Cunty-warsaw</etd:Powiat>
      <etd:Gmina>Prov-warsaw</etd:Gmina>
      <etd:Ulica>1Maja</etd:Ulica>
      <etd:NrDomu>7</etd:NrDomu>
      <etd:Miejscowosc>Warsaw</etd:Miejscowosc>
      <etd:KodPocztowy>01-607</etd:KodPocztowy>
      <etd:Poczta>Post-warsaw-1</etd:Poczta>
    </tns:AdresPodmiotu>
  </tns:Podmiot1>
</tns:JPK>
```

However, when we have larger datasets (using request_id := 233), it runs for a very long time and the file size is over 1 GB.
For even larger datasets, it runs for a very long time and it errors out with:

```
ORA-10260: limit size (1048576) of the PGA heap set by event 10261 exceeded
```

Below are the following limitations I am faced with and the steps i have taken so far:

1. I cannot use dbms_xmldom.writetofile or UTL_FILE packages because it needs a named directory (see: [Use dbms_xmldom.writetofile without a Named Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573615/use-dbms-xmldom-writetofile-without-a-named-directory))
2. I can only use DBMS_OUTPUT or FND_FILE to write to the output.
3. I have confirmed the length of time the program runs is not because of the query, but it's with the writing of the output file.
4. I cannot change the PGA settings.
5. I can't use SQL*Plus.
6. I also can't create another program to do the spooling to a file.

Is there a way to optimize how the file is being written?

Comment: why not use replacement parameters and spool to a file w/o and pl/sql looping?

Comment: @OldProgrammer are you talking about using SQL*Plus? I also can't. This needs to be run from an application. I also can't create another program to do the spooling. Those were the restrictions given to me.

Comment: Why do you not create a DIRECTORY? - You may ask your DBA to do it.

Comment: IDK why all those limitations.  Sounds like some people in your company need to get educated.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: i can't use a directory as per Restriction#1. The directory of the output files changes per execution.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, this is because it's a proprietary application that's running this script. and the output will be the one visible to customers.

Comment: How is the application running the script - it looks like it probably is calling SQL\*Plus, or SQLcl, from the `set` command? And how is it retrieving the output to present to the customer? You refer to it being written to a file - when/where does that happen? It would be helpful to explain the setup. And what is the maximum size you have to handle - if it's less that 2GB you could maybe avoid PL/SQL?

Comment: @AlexPoole, the application(EBS) is calling a Stored Procedure. The code i posted is the gist of the Procedure. It's using a proprietary procedure `FND_FILE` to display the output, it's similar to DBMS_OUTPUT. I'm not sure if there's a maximum size it can handle. i'm open to using PL/SQL + Java but i'm not sure how.

Comment: When you are open for Java then write a function which returns result as `XMLTYPE` or RefCursor (or generate the XML even completely in Java). Your current design is quite ugly.

Comment: i'll look into your suggestion on Java. is there a better way for this to be written in PL/SQL? This isn't my code by the way, just building on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to indent an XML I use this procedure, perhaps it could solve your problem.

```
PROCEDURE MakePrettyXml(xmlString IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS

    xmlDocFragment DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDOCUMENTFRAGMENT;
    xslProc DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSOR;
    xsl DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.STYLESHEET;
    xmlStringOut CLOB;
    
BEGIN

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut, TRUE);
    xslProc := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWPROCESSOR; 
    xsl := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWSTYLESHEET(
        '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">'||
            '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>'||
            '<xsl:template match="@*|node( )">'||
                '<xsl:copy>'||
                    '<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node( )"/>'||
                '</xsl:copy>'||
            '</xsl:template>'||
        '</xsl:stylesheet>', NULL);

    xmlDocFragment := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSXSL(p => xslProc, ss => xsl, cl => xmlString);
    DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOCLOB(DBMS_XMLDOM.MAKENODE(xmlDocFragment), xmlStringOut);
        
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREESTYLESHEET(xsl);
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREEPROCESSOR(xslProc);
        
    xmlString := xmlStringOut; 
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut);
        
END MakePrettyXml;
```

When you have very big XML files then it might be better to create them "line-by-line" instead of one single object, i.e. cut the XML into smaller pieces and output them. Of course, you have to spend some effort to ensure a well-formed XML at the end but the size is unlimited in principle.